# Loading DLL in C++

Tags: c++, dll

I'm trying to load a DLL in `LoadLibrary` way. Here is the `.h` file of my DLL:

```
#ifdef CALLBACKTESTDLL_EXPORTS
#define CALLBACKTESTDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)    
#else
#define CALLBACKTESTDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

typedef int(CALLBACK *p)(char*);  

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall StrToInt(char* InputString);     

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) char* __stdcall NumCompare(p FuncP, char* InputString, int b);
```

There are two functions in it. `StrToInt` convert the input `char*` into `int`. Another one is `NumCompare`, where `StrToInt` is called and its return is compared with another input `int` then `NumCompare` reuturns the comparision result. These two functions are exported to a DLL called `callbacktestDLL.dll`.

Now I want to call this DLL in `LoadLibrary` way. (The `pragma comment(lib,"callbacktestDLL")` way is already tested successfully so I want test another way).

In order to call the DLL functions, this is what I'm doing in `CallDLL.cpp`:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

typedef int (*P_to_Func1)(char*);       //pointer for StrToInt

typedef char* (*P_to_Func2)(P_to_Func1, char*, int);        //pointer for NumCompare


int main()
{
    //load DLL：
    HINSTANCE LDLL = LoadLibrary("callbacktestDLL.dll");

    if (LDLL == NULL)
    {
        printf("DLL loading failed");
        FreeLibrary(LDLL);
    }
    else
    {
        P_to_Func1 p1 = (P_to_Func1)GetProcAddress(LDLL, "_StrToInt@4");

        if (p1 = NULL)
        {
            printf("StrToInt loading failed");
        };

        P_to_Func2 p2 = (P_to_Func2)GetProcAddress(LDLL, "_NumCompare@12");
        if (p2 = NULL)
        {
            printf("NumCompare loading failed");
        };

        //Call StrToInt：
        std::cout << p1("1234") << std::endl;
        //call NumCompare：
        p2(p1, "1234", 20);
        //release：
        FreeLibrary(LDLL);
    };
    return 0;
}
```

These are the functions' names shown by depends:
[image]

When I generate the `CallDLL` project, there is no error and generated successfully. However, when I run the project, a dialog box jumps out and says `CallDLL.exe has stopped` and a `cmd` window says "press any key to continue". Could somebody be so kind to help me understand and solve this problem?

Comment: Change `if (p1 = NULL)` to `if (p1 == NULL)`

Comment: Oh, that's a mistake. I changed it but still have the problem. I use F10 to check the code. And found out something is wrong in `std::cout << p1("1234") << std::endl;`

Comment: That `__stdcall` keyword is important, you'll need it in the function pointer declarations on the caller side.

Comment: Why are you using mangled names, like "_NumCompare@12", use the C ABI, declare the functions as extern 'C' and use the normal names.

Comment: @VivekSubramanian You mean I should include the `.h` of that DLL, and use normal names in `LoadLibrary`?

Comment: @BenVoigt Your answer solved my problem, I add `__stdcall` into the pointer declarations and it worked.

Comment: Are you compiling for x64 or x86?

Comment: @KillzoneKid: If OP experiences this problem, then it's for *x86*.

Comment: @VivekSubramanian:  Those are `extern "C"`+`__stdcall` mangled names, not C++ mangling.  C++ mangling would encode the parameter types not just the number of bytes (because C++ allows having overloads with the same size arguments as long as the types are different).  To expose "normal" names to `GetProcAddress`, a DEF file is needed when linking the DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling conventions are quite important, and because `GetProcAddress` works with the export table, there is no type information, and the compiler can't catch your mistake.

The difference between Visual C++'s default calling convention (`__cdecl`) and `__stdcall` is in argument-passing order and who is responsible for restoring the stack pointer.  `__cdecl` pushes the last argument onto the stack first, and has the caller remove arguments from the stack.  These choices make "varargs" work.  With `__stdcall`, the first argument is pushed first and the function which is called removes the arguments as it returns.  This choice is a bit more efficient.

When you have a mismatch, binary data gets plunked into the wrong arguments, and then the stack pointer gets adjusted wrong (in your case it gets adjusted twice, but not being adjusted at all would also be possible).  This double adjustment of the stack pointer crashes your program on return from the call to `p1("1234")`.  If you had called `p2(p1, "1234", 20)` first, the misinterpretation of `20` as a function pointer would crash your program... and if it miraculously survived that (decided not to invoke the callback function) the stack mismatch when `p2` returns would cause a crash.

Pay close attention to calling conventions and you can avoid this pain.

Comment: This is the most specific answer.